# Prove that $ \csc^2(z)= \sum_{n=- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z-n\pi)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that 
$$ \csc^2(z)= \sum_{n=- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z-n\pi)^2} \quad \quad (\textrm{for all }z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{n \pi \colon n \in \mathbb{Z}\}) $$

---

The course I have uses this book and its' definitions: http://web.math.ku.dk/noter/filer/koman-12.pdf. So any theorems about complex analysis not stated in here, I have to prove myself.

Right now, I have two ideas for tackling the problem. Both of them relies on Theorem 7.16 in the book

[image]

**Idea 1:** Somehow use Theorem 7.16 and Mertens Theorem on the Cauchy Product. However I can't quite make it work since this series is from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Keep in my mind I also have to prove the Mertens Theorem as it is not stated in the book.

**Idea 2:** Somehow modifying the proof of Theorem 7.16 which uses Partial Fraction Decomposition.

I am asking if someone can help me choose between the two ideas and perhaps give me a headstart. If neither if them works or there is a third and better approach, please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: I would go with your second idea. Alternatively, if you have the partial fraction decomposition of the cotangent function, you can use $ - \frac{{d\cot z}}{{dz}} = \csc ^2 z$.

Comment: No but I can prove it or look to this proof if necessary: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Partial_Fractions_Expansion_of_Cotangent. However say I went with this approach. How and why can I differentiate this infinite series? Which assumptions are at play?

Comment: Uniform convergence of the series on compact subsets of its domain is enough to justify termwise differentiability.